# Matrix from list of arrays compiling into one row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I have 165 lists of 4120 numbers (floats) that I am trying to form into a matrix.

```
e_matrix = np.asmatrix([np.array(xi) for xi in embeddings])
e_matrix.shape
```

But this gives me a shape of (1,168). Why is this not a matrix of shape (4120,168)?

The type for each element in list "embeddings" is '<class 'list'>

Comment: What is `e_matrix.dtype`?  I suspect you have created a matrix with dtype `object`, perhaps because there is at least one element of `embeddings` whose length is different from the others.

Comment: try renaming into `e_matrix = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in embeddings])`

Comment: If the lists all have the same length, then `np.array(embeddings)` should make a 2d array, (165,4120) shape.  Or `np.stack(embeddings, axis=1)` if you want the transpose.  But the (1,168) shape suggests that your lists don't all match.  Try `[len(i) for i in embeddings]`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that was the problem, one list was a different length, thanks all!